# jQuery html function not adding script tags to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am dynamically updating the content of a div using websockets. The websocket returns raw HTML and I am using jQuery to replace the div's html with the value from the websocket.

I have tried using both .html() and .append(), both of which seem to execute the scripts, but not add them to the DOM. I am able to display the content, but I want users to be able to see the script tags when they use Inspect Element (I am displaying client-side authentication challenges).

Is there any way to replace the html of an element with jQuery while not filtering out any script tags?

Comment: Sure seem to work for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/3n95p/

Comment: Try not using jquery. element.innerHTML = newStuff.

Comment: @adeneo I just tried the exact same thing in jQuery 1.7.2 (what I am using for the site) and it does not work. I am assuming it may be version-dependent

Comment: @ZackArgyle if I used innerHTML, it will add it to the DOM, but not evaluate the JavaScript. I suppose I could do a combination of both.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work in older versions of jQuery for some strange reason. Update your jQuery or use innerHTML as suggested by Zack instead, but note that I'm splitting the `</script>` tag, as any closing script tag encountered in a string literal in javascript will close the current script tag as well and cause errors, this is why jQuery generally removes script tags from HTML strings.

Comment: @adeneo upgrading to the latest jQuery worked. If you post an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Zack: `innerHTML` does not execute `script` tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML#Security_considerations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of jQuery's `html()` should insert the script tag, it seems older versions of `html()` (jQuery 1.7) removes script tags from the HTML string passed.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3n95p/)